# How to get a sub portion of a string using perl?

Tags: regex, perl

Here's the string I'm using and the display of this string can be rearrange in any other and in my case, I'm only interested in getting the first parenthesis text and putting the remaining text on its on line..

For example,

```
(test network) or test(section memory) or test(section storage)
```

Ideal output:

```
test section network
or test(section memory) or test(section storage)
```

Here's the perl code I attempt to use to accomplish this goal.

```
    while(<readline>)
    {
        $_ =~ s/^\(test (.*)\)(.*)/test section $1\n$2/gi;
    }
```

The output does not match the ideal output I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
s/^\(test ([^)]*)\)\s*(.*)/test section $1\n$2/gi
```

Answer (score 2):

perreal answer seems good, but here is another solution using ungreedyness (using ? after the *)

```
s/^\(test (.*?)\)\s*(.*)/test section $1\n$2/gi
```

Answer (score 1):

your expression is being too greedy, the first bit (test (.*)) matches up the the last ) on the line, so dosn't work.

Make the expression non-greedy

```
s/^\(test (.*?)\)(.*)/test section $1\n$2/gi
```

probably don't need the g (global) modifier either.